# How do I solve differential equation $\ddot{y}-\dot{y}-20y=5e^{-4t}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\ddot{y}-\dot{y}-20y=0$

I solved this quadratic equation. So $y(t)=C_1*e^{-4t}+C_2*e^{5t}$.

Than $y(t)=Ae^{-4t}t^2$. So I have done first two derrivatives of this.

Than I get: $-18Ae^{-4t}t+2Ae^{-4t}=5e^{-4t}$.

What is next that I should? It would be easy if there wasn't  $-18Ae^{-4t}t$.

Comment: Where does $Ae^{-4t}t^2$ come from?

Comment: I think
$$
y(t)=C_1e^{-4t}+C_2e^{5t}
$$
is what you are looking for

Comment: Do you want to solve $$\ddot{y}-\dot{y}-20y=t^2e^{-4t}\qquad{\large ?}$$

Comment: The method of undetermined coefficients would probably be the best way to solve this. Check out @RobertZ post on this.

You solve the homogenous equation, finding a linearly independent solution for it, and then use a "template" in order to solve for the non-homogenous portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to complete your task you should find a particular solution of $$\ddot{y}-\dot{y}-20y=5e^{-4t}.$$ 
We will use the Method of Undetermined Coefficients:
since $-4$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of order $1$, you can look for a solution of this form $y_p=t\cdot Ae^{-4t}$. Now we plug it in the ODE and we get
$$(16t-8)Ae^{-4t}-(-4t+1)Ae^{-4t}-20Ate^{-4t}=5e^{-4t}$$
that is $(16t-8)A-(-4t+1)A-20At=5$ or $-9A=5$ and finally $A=-5/9$.

Hence the general solution is $y(t)=C_1e^{-4t}+C_2e^{5t}-\frac{5}{9}te^{-4t}$.

Answer (score 0):

for the particular solution make the ansatz $$y_p=e^{-4x}(Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D)$$

Answer (score 0):

The most generic approach to handle such problems is the Greens' function approach.  Denote by $f_i(x)$ for $i=1,2$ the solutions to the homogeneous ODE.
The generic solution to the non-homogeneous ODE reads as follows:
\begin{equation}
y(x) = \int\limits_0^\infty G(x,\xi) \cdot rhs(\xi) d \xi
\end{equation}
Here $G(x,\xi)$ is the Greens function and $rhs(\xi)$ is the right hand side.
The Greens' function (as a function of $x$ and fixed $\xi$) satisfies the same ODE as the original one except that the zero on the right hand side is being replaced by a $\delta(x-\xi)$. Therefore the Green's function reads:
\begin{equation}
G(x,\xi) := \left\{
\begin{array}{rr}
C_1^+ f_1(x) + C_2^+ f_2(x) & \quad \mbox{if $x \ge \xi$} \\
C_1^- f_1(x) + C_2^- f_2(x) & \quad \mbox{if $x < \xi$} \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
Here the constants depend on $\xi$ only. Since the Greens function satisfies the ODE it has to be "smooth enough". It needs to be continuous at $x=\xi$ and, in addition, the first derivative has to have a jump by magnitude one at $x=\xi$. From that it follows that:
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{r} C_1^+\\ C_2^+ \end{array}
\right)
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{r} C_1^-\\ C_2^- \end{array}
\right)
+
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
f_1(\xi) & f_2(\xi) \\
f_1^{'}(\xi) & f_2^{'}(\xi) 
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{r} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
Combining the equations together we obtain the final result:
\begin{equation}
y(x) = C_1^- f_1(x) + C_2^- f_2(x) + \int\limits_0^x \frac{f_1(\xi) f_2(x) - f_1(x) f_2(\xi)}{{\mathcal W}[f_1,f_2](\xi)} \cdot rhs(\xi) d\xi
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal W}[f_1,f_2](\xi) := \left|
\begin{array}{rr} f_1(\xi) & f_2(\xi) \\ f_1^{'}(\xi) & f_2^{'}(\xi)\end{array}
\right|
\end{equation}
is the Wronskian of the the ODE.
In our case the Wronskian equals ${\mathcal W}[f_1,f_2](\xi) = 9 e^\xi$ and the generic solution reads:
\begin{equation}
y(x) = C_1^- e^{-4 x} + C_2^- e^{5 x} + \frac{5}{81} e^{-4 x} \left(-1+ e^{9 x} - 9 x\right)
\end{equation}
Note that the solution above is the same as that given by Robert Z above(Why?).